# How to play a sound when my app launches

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

How would I play a sound when my iOS app launches; should I use an `AVPlayer` to play an mp3 file?

Answer (score 0):

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` use below code to play audio

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pathToYourFile]; 
AVPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];

[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: How can you put this code in applicationdidfinishlaunching ?

Comment: by mistaken change to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions